# Assigning the level of the node

Tags: dataframe

I have a game tree (economics) structured in a dataframe like this:

Node - Parent Node

b   -   a

c   -   a

d   -   b

e   -   b

f   -   b

g   -   c

h    -  d

i.e. the uppermost node in the tree is a which leads to b and c. b in tun leads to d, e, f and c leads to g. and finally node d leads to h. I want to create an additional column which tells me the level at which the node occurs, i.e., I want an output which is something like this:

Node - Parent Node - Level

b   -   a       -      1

c    -  a      -       1

d    -  b        -     2

e   -   b       -      2

f   -   b        -     2

g   -   c       -      2

h  -    d       -      3

How do I do this?

Moreover, if the data is not organised and is random that is the rows are not ordered the way I have shown (but it always has information on what the parent node is of a specific node), is their a way of solving the same problem and assigning the level of the node?

I know this might be super simple but I am new to Python and I didn't know how to search for this specifically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you always start at your root, and ordered, you just travel down your tree and add a level when you visit a new child node.
If its not ordered i guess you could travel backwards and count the steps until you hit the root.

You'll probably need some recursive funtion to traverse around the tree.

Comment: Thanks Loxx, I am exactly looking for that recursive function. Any idea how to define it?